# Drupal inline_entity_form table style input

Tags: entities

My custom entity has a entity reference ( with Inline entity form - Multiple values) widget.

On entity edit form I need to show "entity reference" direct edit form in a table row ( in other words each entity should have a horizontal form layout).

How to implement it in custom controller which already extended from EntityInlineEntityFormController ?